# How to know app going to reach max heap memory?

Tags: android, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am making Image gallery app with various types of image in term of resolution and size.
As per my observation, when app try to load large image its throws OutOfMemory.

1. How can i prevent app from OutofMemory?
2. Is there any way to get notification before app get crash because of OutOfMemory?
3. How can i know app going to reach heap capacity?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i prevent app from OutofMemory?

Allocate less memory. For example, with images, use things like `inSampleSize` on `BitmapFactory.Options` to only load into memory what you need, not the whole image.

Also, if your images will be the same resolution, use `inBitmap` to reuse already-allocated `Bitmap` objects, rather than let them get garbage-collected.

> Is there any way to get notification before app get crash because of OutOfMemory?

No, because you are not out of memory.

> How can i know app going to reach heap capacity?

You are not reaching "heap capacity".

Dalvik's garbage collector is a non-compacting (or non-moving) garbage collector, and so over time your heap becomes fragmented. `OutOfMemoryError` means that you are trying to allocate something for which there is no single free block big enough. I wrote [a blog post that explains this a bit more](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/16/art-garbage-collection.html) and explains how the new ART runtime will help in this regard in the future.

Comment: Thanks Commonsware. I am managing byte[] of images and on the basis of requirement decoding byte into bitmap. I want to clean up byte[] if app requires more memory. So i want to get update from system that now u have no enough memory to load bitmap, so i clear some Array elements.

Comment: @RohanPatel: "So i want to get update from system that now u have no enough memory to load bitmap, so i clear some Array elements." -- wrap your `Bitmap` logic in a `try`/`catch` block and watch for `OutOfMemoryError` exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

`getMemoryClass()` gives  you an estimation of how much memory you have available in your application.
 `getLargeMemoryClass()` gives you an estimation of the large heap size you can allocate to your application.
So debug your application first to know where does it throw an exception exactly (line) then add logs to see how much memory you got.

Comment: but you should keep in mind that you should  never request a large heap simply because you've run out of memory. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html